# Is there a configuration option for using Unix domain socket to connect to SQL Server Instance?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, google-cloud-platform

I am attempting to link an app engine service to an instance of SQL Server on the Google Cloud Platform using [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine)

My service is a nodejs application and I am using the [`mssql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#microsoft--contributors-node-v8-driver-for-nodejs-for-sql-server) library to connect to my database.

The documentation only describes using TCP/IP (an ip address):

```
const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool({
    user: '...',
    password: '...',
    server: 'localhost',
    database: '...'
})
```

If I try to use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` for my `server`, the connection fails:

[image: The GCP console when testing: error]

I need help with one of the following:

1. How can I connect to the SQL instance using TCP/IP using the `mssql` library?
2. What is the configuration option for the connection pool using unix domain socket?

Comment: Hey, can you specify if you are using App Engine Flex or Standard, and as far as I understood from your question. Is the SQL Server instance that you wish to connect hosted on GCP (Cloud SQL) or is it an external one that you have mounted already?

Comment: The SQL server instance is hosted on GCP.  The Engine environment is Engine standard.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually done this one yet, so I'm guessing a little bit, but try one of these:

1. Pass the unix socket to the `server` config tag.
2. Pass `localhost` to the `server` tag and the unix socket value to the `port` tag.

Comment: I haven't gotten around to trying this just yet. I will give it a go.

Comment: Let us know if it works for you Josh, if not we can look deeper into it.

Comment: @JoshSharkey What did you find here? Any luck? I am still struggling :/

Comment: Ah, so tried these and they didn't work? I don't have anything else off the top of my head, but like I mentioned in the other thread, I don't use/know mssql. :(

Comment: Thanks for checking. I tried using this configuration by following the documentation but I got stuck looking for a *missing* Unix socket file under /cloudsql/. Without that I'm unable to verify whether your suggestion works. I'm shifting towards a MySQL solution at the moment.

Comment: You shouldn't need any file there, you just need to pass the socket path value: `/cloudsql/${process.env.CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME}` Or do you mean that's the error you're seeing?